# Density of substances slightly above and below the freezing point

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, phase-transition, density

I would find a table useful where I can look up the density of various substances just above / just below their freezing point in order to find out how the density changes as the phase changes. But I find it hard to find this information for any substance other than water. Does anybody know a source to find this data for more substances?